# SQL Server Express Failed to Install

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am attempting to install SQL Server Express (as part of the Visual Studio 2010 Professional installation), but it is failing. I am receiving this error log.

```
[06/22/11,16:31:39] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[06/22/11,16:31:40] setup.exe: [2] Duplicate module ID: {0AFE11CA-57AA-4F66-90BE-284F0F3A5ABD}
[06/22/11,16:32:12] setup.exe: [2] Duplicate component in install order: SQL EULAs
[06/22/11,16:32:12] setup.exe: [2] Duplicate component in install order: SQL EULAs
[06/22/11,16:32:12] setup.exe: [2] Duplicate component in install order: SQL EULAs
[06/22/11,17:07:55] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[06/22/11,17:07:55] setup.exe: [2] Duplicate module ID: {0AFE11CA-57AA-4F66-90BE-284F0F3A5ABD}
[06/23/11,10:39:33] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[06/23/11,10:39:33] setup.exe: [2] Duplicate module ID: {0AFE11CA-57AA-4F66-90BE-284F0F3A5ABD}
[06/23/11,10:40:22] setup.exe: [2] Duplicate component in install order: SQL EULAs
[06/23/11,10:40:22] setup.exe: [2] Duplicate component in install order: SQL EULAs
[06/23/11,10:40:22] setup.exe: [2] Duplicate component in install order: SQL EULAs
[06/23/11,10:53:48] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[06/23/11,10:53:48] setup.exe: [2] Duplicate module ID: {0AFE11CA-57AA-4F66-90BE-284F0F3A5ABD}
[06/23/11,13:19:26] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[06/23/11,13:19:26] setup.exe: [2] Duplicate module ID: {0AFE11CA-57AA-4F66-90BE-284F0F3A5ABD}
[06/23/11,16:47:36] Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64): [2] Error code -2068643839 for this component is not recognized.
[06/23/11,16:47:36] Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64): [2] Component Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64) returned an unexpected value.
***EndOfSession***
```

I'm reading various articles which point towards something being wrong in the register, but I can't find anything specific. Any suggestions for what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was in the system-wide permissions and, within Windows 7, I was not receiving enough "admin" access (since policies were more fine-grained in Windows 7). Once I received the correct access, everything worked correctly.

Answer (score -1):

JasCav, this seems to have happened to many people, and for whatever reason, the second time they try to install it, it works. I would try again at least one more time.

Also, as a kind of secret thing (at least at the time, this was not easily found on the Internet...but who knows now?) that I figured out a long time ago: I have had SQL Service Pack updates fail before, and I resolved it by creating a Software Restriction Policy. This may not be related here, but a good idea to do, and it is still possible it may help.

1. For Windows 7 (very similar on other MS OS'es), go to Control Panel>Administrative Tools>Local Security Policy and double-click.
2. Right-click on "Software Restriction Policies", and click "New Software Restriction Policies" (the exact wording varies with XP, but it is clear it is the same thing).
3. Double-click "Enforcement", and set the options to: "All software files", and "All users except local administrators".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it out tomorrow. One question - when you say "try again at least one more time" - I don't see an option to try to reinstall SQL Server from the VS2010 install. Do I have to do an uninstall of everything and then a reinstall? Just wondering about clarification. Thanks!

Comment: @JasCav I think they meant the whole package, since they also had problems installing VS2010.

Comment: Just finished trying this out. Unfortunately, it didn't work. :-\ Bummer.